# java.lang.nullpointerexception in j2me

Tags: java-me, nullpointerexception, smartcard, apdu, mifare

I am writing an application for read the mifare card,but when I pass the APDU the error occur that on emulator "java.lang.nullpointerexception".I have successfully detect the ISO14443_CARD after that I pass the APDU like

```
if (tp.hasTargetType(TargetType.ISO14443_CARD)){
  form.append("Target is ISO14443_CARD\n");

 try { 
            static byte[]   APDU_AUTH1 = { (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x05,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x00,(byte)0xfc,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x00};
            static byte[]   STATUS_BYTE = {(byte)0x90,(byte)0x00}; 
        if(STATUS_BYTE == iso14443.exchangeData(APDU_LOAD_KEY))
        {
         String value1 = new String("Hai!");
         textfield1.setString(value1);
         form.append(textfield1);

        }
        else
        {
            String value1 = new String("Hello!");
             textfield1.setString(value1);
             form.append(textfield1);
        }



     } 
    catch (Exception ex) { 
        form.append(ex.toString()); 
        } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of `iso14443` or `textfield1` objects is likely null.

With the way you debug things (quite smart BTW, my congratulations), you could log the checks about as follows:

```
form.append("\n\n iso14443 is null: [" + (iso14443 == null)
        + "],\n textfield1 is null: [" + (textfield1 == null) + "]");
```